# Help with AMD Catalyst installation

Tags: ati, software-installation

I'm trying to install the AMD Catalyst driver, to use my Radeon HD7770 with Ubuntu 13.10.

I was following [these steps](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_BETA.2FEXPERIMENTAL), and I've success in the `wget` download, but in driver installation, something is wrong...

I use this code:

```
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy
```

and get this error:

```
Created directory fglrx-install.1XtqFA
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-13.35.1005.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/saucy
Resolving build dependencies...
apt 0.9.9.1~ubuntu1 for amd64 compiled on Sep 11 2013 17:45:21
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-get is a simple command line interface for downloading and
installing packages. The most frequently used commands are update
and install.

Commands:
   update - Retrieve new lists of packages
   upgrade - Perform an upgrade
   install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
   remove - Remove packages
   autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages
   purge - Remove packages and config files
   source - Download source archives
   build-dep - Configure build-dependencies for source packages
   dist-upgrade - Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)
   dselect-upgrade - Follow dselect selections
   clean - Erase downloaded archive files
   autoclean - Erase old downloaded archive files
   check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies
   changelog - Download and display the changelog for the given package
   download - Download the binary package into the current directory

Options:
  -h  This help text.
  -q  Loggable output - no progress indicator
  -qq No output except for errors
  -d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
  -s  No-act. Perform ordering simulation
  -y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
  -f  Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place
  -m  Attempt to continue if archives are unlocatable
  -u  Show a list of upgraded packages as well
  -b  Build the source package after fetching it
  -V  Show verbose version numbers
  -c=? Read this configuration file
  -o=? Set an arbitrary configuration option, eg -o dir::cache=/tmp
See the apt-get(8), sources.list(5) and apt.conf(5) manual
pages for more information and options.
                       This APT has Super Cow Powers.
Unable to resolve  debhelper  dh-modaliases execstack.  Please manually install and try again.
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: dpkg-buildpackage: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:13.350-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. 
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.l4U467
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
             dkms.conf \
             fglrx.install \
             fglrx-dev.install \
             fglrx-dev.links \
             fglrx-amdcccle.install \
             fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
             fglrx.dirs \
             fglrx.links \
             fglrx.postinst \
             fglrx.postrm \
             fglrx.preinst \
             fglrx.prerm \
             overrides/fglrx; do \
        sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
            -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
            -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
            -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
            -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
            -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
            -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx-dev|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#||g" \
            -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#GRUBBLKLISTDIR#|usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#CVERSION#|13.350|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
            -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
            -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
            debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
    done
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
        etc \
        lib \
        module \
        usr \
        xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: `module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
        arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
        usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:13.350-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. 
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.UEq8hK
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
             dkms.conf \
             fglrx.install \
             fglrx-dev.install \
             fglrx-dev.links \
             fglrx-amdcccle.install \
             fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
             fglrx.dirs \
             fglrx.links \
             fglrx.postinst \
             fglrx.postrm \
             fglrx.preinst \
             fglrx.prerm \
             overrides/fglrx; do \
        sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
            -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
            -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
            -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
            -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
            -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
            -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx-dev|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#||g" \
            -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#GRUBBLKLISTDIR#|usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#CVERSION#|13.350|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
            -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
            -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
            debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
    done
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
        etc \
        lib \
        module \
        usr \
        xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: `module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
        arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
        usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:13.350-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. 
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.YU05HO
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
             dkms.conf \
             fglrx.install \
             fglrx-dev.install \
             fglrx-dev.links \
             fglrx-amdcccle.install \
             fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
             fglrx.dirs \
             fglrx.links \
             fglrx.postinst \
             fglrx.postrm \
             fglrx.preinst \
             fglrx.prerm \
             overrides/fglrx; do \
        sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
            -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
            -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
            -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
            -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
            -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
            -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
            -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx-dev|g" \
            -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#||g" \
            -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
            -e "s|#GRUBBLKLISTDIR#|usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist|g" \
            -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
            -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
            -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
            -e "s|#CVERSION#|13.350|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
            -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
            -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
            -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
            debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
    done
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
        etc \
        lib \
        module \
        usr \
        xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: `module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
        arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
        usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.1XtqFA
```

EDIT: when I use only `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run` it runs fine, but I want to use it compiled to Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have the command `dh`.

Using `apt-file search -F /usr/bin/dh` it seems that the package in which this command is found is `debhelper`. So

```
sudo apt-get install debhelper
```

should solve it.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I can play and use my real monitor resolution :)